# How to use condition in expression in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, expression, conditional-statements

I'm making a small page that show how the number filter work:

```
Number: <input type="text" ng-model="nomber"><br/>
fractionSize: <input type="text" ng-model="fractionSize"><br/>
gives: {{ nomber | number:fractionSize }}
```

If i write a number, it will work, but if I decide to had a nomber in fractionSize, but than remove it, it gives me NaN.

I would like to have a condition in

```
{{ nomber | number:fractionSize }}
```

that will tell my condition to not try to use fractionSize if the input is empty.

Comment: could you provide a plunkr or jsfiddle that show the error?

Comment: I don't know how to use those, but I my explication should be quite enough.  It's not a complicated error at all and what really matters is that I could remove ":fractionSize" from my expression if the "fractionSize" input is empty.

Comment: i guess the solution could be simply add <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="fractionSize" ng-if="fractionSize">

Comment: It ens up hidding the input because of ng-if="fractionSize"

Comment: you should edit the title of the question btw, is not very clear what your are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should redefine the filter you are using, cause by design angular would return NaN, as you can see here: [Number filter should not format NaN to empty string](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10005)

Here a custom filter that accomplish what are you looking for:

```js
angular.module('plunker', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.nomber = 0;
    $scope.fractionSize = 0;
  })
.filter('textOrNumber', function ($filter) {
    return function (input, fractionSize) {
        if (isNaN($filter('number')(input, fractionSize))) {
            return $filter('number')(input, 1);
        } else {
            return $filter('number')(input, fractionSize);
        };
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.*" data-semver="1.4.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    Number: <input type="number" ng-model="nomber"><br/>
    fractionSize: <input type="number" ng-model="fractionSize"><br/>
    gives: {{ nomber | textOrNumber: fractionSize}}
  </body>

</html>
```

EDIT: 
An improvements can be, if we consider that and empty denominator in a fraction can be evaluated as 1, so you can edit your code returning `$filter('number')(input, 1);` when isNan() has evaluated true.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RO5fxVbTwx0fy2WLyfvr?p=preview) you can find a working plunkr.

Comment: It's sure that it would work with a module, but I was more aiming for something quick and easy in the html file. Anyway, It's really not a big deal.

Comment: i will not tell with 100% of certainty that there's no solution for doing this as you imagine into the html, but i'm not able to find another solution rather than this one i propose to you. I hope it will be fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `type="number"`instead of `text`.

```
<input type="number" min="0" ng-model="fractionSize">
```

I think that should solve your problem for `NaN`. And as you say that it works for number, it should solve your problem.

And if you want to add a condition instead then:

```
Number: <input type="number" ng-model="nomber"><br/>
fractionSize: <input type="number" min="0" required ng-model="fractionSize"><br/>
    gives: <span ng-if="typeOf nomber ==='number'">{{ nomber | number:fractionSize }}</span>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/moidmw/sttuccsg/) is the working fiddle.

Comment: still gives me NaN when I empty the fractionSize field

Comment: What did you try...? I have edit the answer, try that. Actually your were using the `nomber` modal value and I applied the condition on `fractionNumber`

Comment: I tried with your edited version and it doesn't work. Is there anyway to just do something like:
{{ nombre | number if(my_condition){+":fractionSize"} }}

Comment: No, that wont work. And now, I got it working.. Just add `required` field to the second input. That will do the trick.

Comment: It's still not what I'm hopping for, but thanks for your help, it's that important, I was really just currious to know if I could do {{ nombre | number if(my_condition){+":fractionSize"} }} like I asked previously, but you told that I can't, so I have my answer :)